# adding component to the frame using borderlayout

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe

how to get the same look using using layout

```
    package item;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
/**
 *
 * @author isslam
 */
public class MyFrameMain extends JFrame{
    Equipment newq = new Equipment();
    private final JLabel iLabel;
    private final JLabel nLabel;
    private final JTextField iJTextField;
    private final JTextField nJTextField;
    private final JTextField swTextField;
    private final JTextField hwTextField;
    private final JLabel jItemCounter;
    private final JTextArea reSoulte;
    private final JButton addButton;
    private final JButton showButton;
    private final JButton copyButton;
    private final JButton exitButton;

    public MyFrameMain(String title){
    super(title);
    setTitle(title);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(MyFrameMain.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    iJTextField = new JTextField();
    nJTextField = new JTextField();
    swTextField = new JTextField();
    hwTextField = new JTextField();
    nLabel = new JLabel("ID: ");
    iLabel = new JLabel("Name: ");
    jItemCounter = new JLabel("Number of current Item");

    reSoulte = new JTextArea(15,20);
    reSoulte.setEditable(false);

    addButton = new  JButton("Add an item into the Array");
    showButton = new JButton("Show all items in the Array");
    copyButton = new JButton("Copy Array into File");
    exitButton = new JButton("Exite");


    JRadioButton rButton1 = new JRadioButton("SW Version",false);
    JRadioButton rButton2 = new JRadioButton("HW Type",false);
    JRadioButton rButton3 = new JRadioButton("General",true);    

     ButtonGroup BGroup = new ButtonGroup();
     BGroup.add(rButton1);
     BGroup.add(rButton2);
     BGroup.add(rButton3);

     JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5,1));
     panel.add(nLabel);
     panel.add(iLabel);
     panel.add(rButton1);
     panel.add(rButton2);
     panel.add(rButton3);

     JPanel bpanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,2));
     bpanel.add(addButton);
     bpanel.add(showButton);
     bpanel.add(copyButton);
     bpanel.add(exitButton);

     JPanel jtfPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5,1));
     jtfPanel.add(iJTextField);
     jtfPanel.add(nJTextField);
     jtfPanel.add(swTextField);
     jtfPanel.add(hwTextField);
     jtfPanel.add(jItemCounter);

     JPanel jtaPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5,1));
     jtaPanel.add(reSoulte);

     Container pane = getContentPane();
     pane.setLayout(null);
     pane.add(panel);
     pane.add(bpanel);
     pane.add(jtfPanel);
     pane.add(jtaPanel);



     Insets insets = pane.getInsets();
     setSize(500 + insets.left + insets.right,500 + insets.top + insets.bottom);

     Dimension size = panel.getPreferredSize();
     panel.setBounds(0 + insets.left, 18 + insets.top,size.width, size.height);

     size = bpanel.getPreferredSize();
     bpanel.setBounds(0 + insets.left, 409 + insets.top,115+size.width, size.height);

     size = jtfPanel.getPreferredSize();
     jtfPanel.setBounds(180 + insets.left, 25 + insets.top,170 +size.width, size.height);

     size = jtaPanel.getPreferredSize();
     jtaPanel.setBounds(0 + insets.left, 150 + insets.top,265 +size.width, size.height);


     exitButton.addActionListener(new ButtonWatcher());

    }

     private class ButtonWatcher implements ActionListener{

         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a){
             System.exit(0);
        }
     }     
}
```

Comment: i can use absolute position but is there any way to done it with out using absolute position

Comment: Follow Java naming conventions if you want people to look at your code. Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. `what is better layout for centering the JTextArea` - you don't even add the text area to the frame. Fix your code to use proper variable names and post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem if you want more help.

Comment: can you tell me what should i do to fix it

Comment: @isslam akkilah: Yes.  Follow camickr's instructions exactly.

Comment: @Gilbert le Blanc ok i did

Comment: @camickr i did fix all what you asked can you tell me how to replace absolute position to be borderlayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can you tell me how to replace absolute position to be borderlayout

The way I see your code:

1. "panel" is displayed in the top left
2. "jtfPanel" is displayed in the top right
3. "jtaPanel" is displayed in the center
4. "bPanel" is displayed in the bottom

BorderLayout has 3 vertical areas to work with NORTH, CENTER and SOUTH so I would suggest you combine "panel" and "jtfPanel" into a another panel, then you will have 3 panels to add to the BorderLayout. Something like:

```
JPanel north = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
north.add(panel, BorderLayout.WEST);
north.add(jtfPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

Container contentPane = getContentPane();
contentPane.add(north, BorderLayout.NORTH);
contentPane.add(jtaPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
contentPane.add(bPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

The main point is that you can nest multiple panels to achieve your desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

Here check this out. I added a main method to run it. I used `EmptyBorder`s for needed spacing. I also grouped panels together which makes layouts easier to work with.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

/**
 *
 * @author isslam
 */
public class MyFrameMain extends JFrame {

    // Equipment newq = new Equipment();
    private final JLabel iLabel;
    private final JLabel nLabel;
    private final JTextField iJTextField;
    private final JTextField nJTextField;
    private final JTextField swTextField;
    private final JTextField hwTextField;
    private final JLabel jItemCounter;
    private final JTextArea reSoulte;
    private final JButton addButton;
    private final JButton showButton;
    private final JButton copyButton;
    private final JButton exitButton;

    public MyFrameMain(String title) {
        //super(title);
        setTitle(title);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(MyFrameMain.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        iJTextField = new JTextField();
        nJTextField = new JTextField();
        swTextField = new JTextField();
        hwTextField = new JTextField();
        nLabel = new JLabel("ID: ");
        iLabel = new JLabel("Name: ");
        jItemCounter = new JLabel("Number of current Item");

        reSoulte = new JTextArea(15, 45);
        reSoulte.setEditable(false);

        addButton = new JButton("Add an item into the Array");
        showButton = new JButton("Show all items in the Array");
        copyButton = new JButton("Copy Array into File");
        exitButton = new JButton("Exite");

        JRadioButton rButton1 = new JRadioButton("SW Version", false);
        JRadioButton rButton2 = new JRadioButton("HW Type", false);
        JRadioButton rButton3 = new JRadioButton("General", true);

        ButtonGroup BGroup = new ButtonGroup();
        BGroup.add(rButton1);
        BGroup.add(rButton2);
        BGroup.add(rButton3);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5, 1));
        panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 75));
        panel.add(nLabel);
        panel.add(iLabel);
        panel.add(rButton1);
        panel.add(rButton2);
        panel.add(rButton3);

        JPanel bpanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 2));
        bpanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(15, 0, 0, 0));
        bpanel.add(addButton);
        bpanel.add(showButton);
        bpanel.add(copyButton);
        bpanel.add(exitButton);

        JPanel jtfPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5, 1));

        jtfPanel.add(iJTextField);
        jtfPanel.add(nJTextField);
        jtfPanel.add(swTextField);
        jtfPanel.add(hwTextField);
        jtfPanel.add(jItemCounter);

        //JPanel jtaPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5, 1));
        //jtaPanel.add(reSoulte);

        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        topPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 20, 0));
        topPanel.add(panel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        topPanel.add(jtfPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        mainPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 10, 10, 10));
        mainPanel.add(bpanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        mainPanel.add(reSoulte, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mainPanel.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        Container pane = getContentPane();
        //pane.setLayout(null);
        //pane.add(panel);
        pane.add(mainPanel);
        //pane.add(jtfPanel);


        //Insets insets = pane.getInsets();
        //setSize(500 + insets.left + insets.right, 500 + insets.top + insets.bottom);

        //Dimension size = panel.getPreferredSize();
        //panel.setBounds(0 + insets.left, 18 + insets.top, size.width, size.height);

        //size = bpanel.getPreferredSize();
       // bpanel.setBounds(0 + insets.left, 409 + insets.top, 115 + size.width, size.height);

       // size = jtfPanel.getPreferredSize();
       // jtfPanel.setBounds(180 + insets.left, 25 + insets.top, 170 + size.width, size.height);

        //size = jtaPanel.getPreferredSize();
        //jtaPanel.setBounds(0 + insets.left, 150 + insets.top, 265 + size.width, size.height);

        exitButton.addActionListener(new ButtonWatcher());

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
             public void run(){
                 MyFrameMain frame = new MyFrameMain("Title");
                 frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                 frame.pack();
                 frame.setResizable(false);
                 //frame.setSize(500, 500);
                 frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                 frame.setVisible(true);

             }
         });
     }

    private class ButtonWatcher implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you but why did you delete super(title) it do nothing i know but i think it make the application run faster is that right or wrong

Comment: No need to call super(title). just set the title when you instantiate your class.